# Methods not updating array information when the size is modified

Tags: java, arrays

My methods are not updating the array's information, thus making multiple actions perormed useless. This only happens when I override the old array with a new one of a diffrent size. Thanks for any help in advance. I know that the code I'm writing is pointless and has already been made. I also realize that I have not created all the methods yet.

Driver class:

```
public class CustomListDriver {
  static CustomList a;
  static Object d = new Object();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] x = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
    CustomList<String> list = new CustomList<String>(x);

    list.set(2, "seven");

    list.add("element", 1);

    System.out.println("\n\n\n");

    list.remove(0);

    System.out.println("\n\n\n");

    list.print();
  }
}
```

Methods:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

  public class CustomList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {

  private T[] a;

  /**
   * Description
   * @param x param description
   * @return return description
   */
  CustomList(T[] array) {
    a = array;

  }

  /**
   * Description
   * @param x param description
   * @return return description
   */
  public CustomList() {
    a = (T[]) new Object[0];
  }

  /**
   * Description
   * @param index param determines 
   * @return return description
   */
  public T get(int index) {
    return a[index];
  }

  /**
   * Description
   * @param x param description
   * @return return description
   */
  public T set(int index, T element) {
    a[index] = element;
    return element;
  }

  /**
   * Description
   * @param x param description
   * @return return description
   */
  public int size() {
    return 1;
  }

  /**
   * Description
   * @param x param description
   * @return return description
   */
  public boolean add(T element, int index) {

    T[] temp = a;
    T[] a = (T[]) new Object[temp.length+1];

    for(int i = 0; i<temp.length; i++) {

      a[i] = temp[i];

      if(i==index) {
        a[index] = element;
        i=a.length;
      }
    }

    for(int f = index+1; f<=temp.length; f++) {
      a[f] = temp[f-1];
    }

    for(int q = 0; q<=a.length-1; q++) {
        System.out.println(a[q]);
      }


    return true;
  }

    /**
     * Description
     * @param x param description
     * @return return description
     */
    public T remove(int index) {

      a[index] = null;



      for(int i = 0; i<=a.length-2; i++)
      {
        if(i == index) {
          a[i] = a[i+1];
          a[i+1] = null;
          index++;
        }
      }

      T[] temp = a;
      T[] a = (T[]) new Object[temp.length-1];

      for(int j = 0; j<a.length; j++)
      {
        a[j] = temp[j];
      }



      for(int q = 0; q<=a.length-1; q++) {
        System.out.println(a[q]);
      }

      a = a;

      return a[0];
    }

    /**
     * Description
     * @param x param description
     * @return return description
     */
    public void clear() {
    }


    public void print() {
      for(int f = 0; f<=a.length-1; f++) {
        System.out.println(a[f]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the output you expect, and what output do you get instead?

Comment: Your `(T[]) new Object[..]` would fail if `T` gets a bound. You should find a proper way to create a generic array. You can find a why on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T[] a = (T[]) new Object[temp.length+1];
```

This line creates a new variable `a` that *shadows* the actual `a`, meaning that it's a completely different variable that happens to be named the same.  It looks like what you want is

```
a = (T[]) new Object[temp.length+1];
```

which refers to the preexisting variable `a`.

Answer (score 1):

This line does nothing, as it is a self-assignment:

```
a = a;
```

I think you might mean:

```
this.a = a;
```

which assigns the value of the local variable `a` to the member variable of the class with the same name.